# Docker image build issue

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-registry, docker-build, docker-buildkit

```
ERROR: failed to solve: myimage: pull access denied, repository does not exist or may require authorization: server message: insufficient_scope: authorization failed

 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/myimage:latest
```

I was trying to build the image with below command

```
docker build -t myimages .
```

My dockerfile is below

```
FROM myimage
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN javac sample.java
CMD [ "java","sample" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

`FROM` should be base image, like

```
FROM openjdk:latest
...
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#from

https://hub.docker.com/_/openjdk

Comment: Sorted man, i was wondering, base package, what i understood is its core dependency , example my case openjdk since the file created was in Java